# Написание функции

Tags: r

Помогите, пожалуйста, начинающему)

Задается число Y.
Есть data.frame из элементов X и Z.

Если Y больше X, то на этих уровнях X надо просуммировать Z между собой.

Как написать такой скрипт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией `which`, что бы найти индексы по условию

Написал пример, можно посмотреть как работает [здесь](http://rextester.com/VJRXZ45029)

```
Y = 2;
X = c(1, 3, 6);
Z = c(1, 2, 3);

df = data.frame(X, Z);

which(df[,1] < Y) # Для того что бы понять как работает, выводим индексы найденные
sum(df[which(df[,1] < Y), 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нет ограничений на использование сторонних пакетов, то я бы использовал `dplyr`. Код более понятент

```
library (dplyr)
Y  <- 4
X  <- c(1, 3, 5, 7)
Z  <- c(10, 20, 30, 40)
df  <- data.frame(X, Z)

# фильтруем исходный `data frame`по условию
df.t  <- filter(df, df$X < Y)

# в результате остается
> df.t
  X Z
1 1 10
2 3 20

# просто суммируем по Z
rslt  <- sum(df.t$Z)
> rslt
[1] 30
```